# Template function with container type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++98, type-deduction

I write a function to iterate over `list`, `vector` or anything with `iterator` on string and that function return a pair of the same kind of container on string....

I wrote the following, but i doesn't compile, I try to catch the container type as C and the Allocator as A.

Important, I'm using C++98 only.

```
template<template<std::string, A> class C, class A>
static std::pair<T<std::string, A>, T<std::string, A> > Check(const T<std::string, A>::iterator &beg, const T<std::string, A>::iterator &end)
{
    //.... 
}
```

To call that code I use:

```
vector<string> toCheck; toCheck += "test1", "test2";
pair<vector<string>, vector<string> > found = Check(toCheck.begin(), check.end());
```

Have you an idea of how to write that function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A template template parameter can only involve template parameters, not template arguments. This should work:

```
template<template<class, class> class C, class A>
static std::pair<C<std::string, A>, C<std::string, A> > Check(const typename C<std::string, A>::iterator &beg, const typename C<std::string, A>::iterator &end)
{
    //.... 
}
```

As @Jarod42 points out in the comments, the above signature doesn't allow type deduction for `C` and `A`. And it doesn't match your use case anyway; for that, use this, which will deduce `C` and `A` just fine:

```
template<template<class, class> class C, class A>
static std::pair<C<std::string, A>, C<std::string, A> > Check(const C<std::string, A> &container)
{
    //.... 
}
```

Comment: Note that compiler cannot deduce type here, user have to provide `C` and `A`

Comment: But can we implement in a way where the compiler deduce C and A ?

Comment: @alexbuisson See the edit. But note that there's no way to make type deduction for the container type work with iterator arguments only.

Comment: Using some type_traits to find *compatible* container from iterator may partially help.

Comment: @Jarod42 I've no time for adding that now; feel free to provide your own answer :-)